# How to specify empty has many active record relationship rspec

Tags: rspec

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, categories: categories) }

context 'when the user has no categories' do
  let(:categories) { [] }
  it { expect(user.category_list).to eq '' }
end
```

In the above code, I am trying to explicitly document in the tests, that categories is an empty relation here or in another words user.categories will return [] But if I specify [], it does not seem to work well with `each` function that I have in the user model

It says undefined method each for the Category model

category_list looks like this

```
def category_list
  # some code
  categories.each do |category|
    # some codee
  end
end
```

In the User model

Comment: Add the tags ruby and rails to get more views.

Answer (score -1):

There's not enough information here to answer the question unfortunately, but here's a hit list:

- How many each calls are in category_list? My best guess is that method has 2 each calls, one on `categories.each` and one on the inner variable `category`, which would return the error "NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #{user.inspect}"
- Check your relationship with categories
- If there are none, it should return `[]`.
- Also, since methods mixing AR can sometimes return non-arrays, I recommend using the `be_empty` matcher which will assert the collection is empty.